# How do I deploy a GitHub repository with lots of interdependent classes? ("Save error: Dependent class is invalid...")

Tags: deployment, error, eclipse, github

I am attempting to deploy [this repository](https://github.com/cirruspath/stripeforce) into a DE instance using Eclipse and the method described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/labs/2011/04/how-to-use-git-github-force-com-ide-open-source-labs-apps.html). When I try to save to server, every class returns an error ("Save error: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation"). I have tried saving them to the server one by one and all at once, and I get the same result either way. I am assuming this is because each class is referencing other classes in the repository that haven't been saved yet. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm still pretty new at this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on [Gearset](https://gearset.com) and in the interests of making our service better I tried to solve your problem with our new [cloud version](https://gearset.com/blog/previewing-gearset-deploy-in-the-cloud). Bad news is that I couldn't get it to deploy from a git clone, but with some tweaks I did get it to work. YMMV of course, I haven't actually tried to use it with Stripe, just deployed it.

That said, if this helps:

When I tried to deploy with [Gearset](https://gearset.com), I got the same error when I did not copy `ExampleWebhookListener.cls` from root into the source directory.

As noted in the GitHub project's README, this file has not been included in `src` by default "to help avoid contributors' own webhook implementations from unintentionally getting committed to this public repo or from being overwritten when they pull in the latest code."

1. To resolve this, copy `ExampleWebhookListener.cls` to `classes/WebhookListener.cls`.

Even after doing so, I had to apply the following fixes to the code as it appears to reference non-existent fields in the `Stripe_Webhook__c.object`:

1. `classes/StripeWebhookListener.cls`: remove line 101: `Event_ID__c = event.id` and the comma in the line before.
2. `classes/WebhookDelayedProcessor.cls`:  remove line 31: `webhook.Error_Message__c = e.getMessage();`.

... and `WebhookListener` failed to correctly override a parent method:
3. `classes/WebhookListener.c`: line 31: add override to get `public override void handle_ChargeSucceeded(...`.

After making the changes above, I managed to get the code to deploy via [Gearset](https://gearset.com).

Comment: This solution worked perfectly! I still haven't tested it with Stripe, but at least I can make progress now.